# How to get the current foreground app in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, ios9

I want to know which app is active, on a non-jailbreaked device.

I know **`sysctl()`** can only be used on iOS 8. I've tried to use **`SrpintBoard`**, but can't get anything. I know some applications implement this function. How can I implement this?

Comment: I'd be really amazed if it were possible.

Comment: Fortunately (for me as a user) this is not possible.

Comment: Can you point to an app (published on the App Store) that does this? Also, since the app getting this info would be in the background, how do you know they got this information?

Comment: and also you are not allowed to do such action from the background.

Comment: enterprise APP，http://m.qianka.com，spend money guide user to download other app . many like this app implement this func on ios9.

Comment: Can you include a link to an actual iOS app, distributed on the App Store?

Comment: And what would be the point of obtaining this information?